# Why is my Android app unable to call another application activity on Android 13?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-activity

I want to call another application activity in my application in the following way, but this only works on Android 12 and below and doesn't work on Android 13. Is there a solution?

`

const val STR_COMPONENT = "com.second.app/OtherActivity"

```
try { 

     val bundle = Bundle().apply { 

         putString(HomeActivity.STR_EXTRA_API, "com.second.app") 

         putString(HomeActivity.STR_THEME_FILE_PATH_EXTRA, path) 

     } 

     val mIntent = Intent().apply { 

         flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP 

         component = ComponentName.unflattenFromString(STR_COMPONENT) 

         putExtras(bundle) 

     } 

     startActivity(mIntent) 

 } catch (io: Exception) { 

     Utility.showToast(context, "not support : ${io.message}") 

 }`
```

What I want my app to be able to call another app's activity (in this case a system app)

Comment: I do not know how you are defining "system app", but pre-installed applications vary *widely* across the tens of thousands of Android device models. There is no requirement for any given device to have a pre-installed app with any particular application ID or with an exported activity with any particular name.